# How to enable a button once text is typed in a particular input field in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, disabled-control

So I am stumped I am trying to enable the `Add` button in this `Material UI dialog` once text is typed in a specific input called `company_name`. I have an `addEnable` boolean state value. I initially set the state to `addEnable` to **false**. Then I am using an `handleInputChanges` for my `onChange` event for the `company_name` input field. In that `handleInputChanges` I use the `prevState` of the `addEnable` to set it to **true**. But the button is not being enabled.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  Paper,
  Grid,
  MenuItem
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form';
import { TextField, Select } from 'final-form-material-ui';

interface CompanyFinancialModalState {
  addEnabled: boolean;
  [key: string]: any;
  values: IValues[];
}

export interface IValues {
  company_name: string;
  critical_technology: string[];
}

interface CompanyFinancialModalProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export class CompanyFinancialModal extends React.Component<
  CompanyFinancialModalProps,
  CompanyFinancialModalState
> {
  constructor(props: CompanyFinancialModalProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      addEnabled: false,
      company_name: '',
      critical_technology: [],
      values: []
    };
  }

  public render() {
    const { open, onClose } = this.props;
    const { addEnabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={onClose}
          className="company-financial-modal"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="company-financial-modal-title">
            {'Company and Financial Data'}
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <div>
              <Form
                onSubmit={this.processFormSubmission}
                // validate={this.validateForm}
                // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
                render={({
                  handleSubmit,
                  /*  reset,  submitting, pristine, */ values
                }) => (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Paper style={{ padding: 16 }}>
                      <Grid container={true} alignItems="flex-start" spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item={true} xs={12}>
                          <Field
                            fullWidth={true}
                            required={true}
                            name="company_name"
                            component={TextField}
                            type="text"
                            label="Company Name"
                            onChange={this.handleInputChanges}
                          />
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </Paper>
                  </form>
                )}
              />
            </div>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              id="company-financial-modal-add"
              disabled={!addEnabled}
              onClick={onClose}
              color="primary"
            >
              Add
            </Button>
            <Button
              id="company-financial-modal-cancel"
              onClick={onClose}
              color="secondary"
              autoFocus={true}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </>
    );
  }

  private handleInputChanges = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value });
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { addEnabled: prevState.addEnabled }
    })
  }
}

export default CompanyFinancialModal;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try using this code Change the button to

```
<Button id="company-financial-modal-add" disabled={this.state.addEnabled} >
 </>
```

> And also change the state as addEnabled to true

```
handleInputChanges=(e)={ if(e.target.value===""){ this.setState( { addEnabled:true } ) } 
else{ this.setState( {

    addEnabled:false } ) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use prevState when handleInputChanges  would be triggered for the second time the button will be disabled again wheras you want the button to be always enabled once there is some input in company_name field.

```
return { addEnabled: true }
```

The function would look like this then

```
private handleInputChanges = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value });
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { addEnabled: true }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you log and see what is the value of addEnabled after you make a change to field?

Comment: I put `console.log(this.state.addEnabled)` in the `handleInputChanges` method and I don't see anything when I type in the input.

Comment: can you just log a simple hello and verify if handleInputChnages is getting called or not?

Comment: Can you recreate a simple working snippet in codesandbox or something so we can work on it?

Comment: Yes I can do that

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you giving assigning the same value to the `addEnabled` state on your `handleInputChanges` function?

This should work

```
private handleInputChanges = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value });
    if (e.currentTarget.value !== "") this.setState(prevState => ({ addEnabled: true }))
    else this.setState(prevState => ({ addEnabled: false }))
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a basic component with JS and it works for me. You can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-c469b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: So I am guessing it has something to do with the `react-final-form` module